# passing the data to the controller

Tags: java, eclipse, jquery

when i run that time,this error will be produced.

> 500 Could not instantiate bean class
>   [org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.service.CatalogService]: Specified
>   class is an interface

Comment: Specify other technologies and frameworks you are using.

Comment: Please elaborate the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you are doing a

```
new CatalogService();
```

Since it is an interface, you can create objects out of it but of some class that **implements** that interface. You can do:

```
public class MyCatalogService implements CatalogService {
   ...
}
```

and

```
CatalogService cs = new MyCatalogService();
```

Read a little more about Java classes, interfaces and inheritance. Ah, and this question was easy; but if you want answers you will probably need to add more detail to your questions.